# How to view the metadata present in an icecast stream using media response?

Tags: actions-on-google

I'm building an action that, through the media response, has to play an icecast stream. In the stream I would have the metadata of the songs. Is there a way to display them for example in the "description" field? The idea is to make them visible for example on google nest.

```
this.$googleAction.$audioPlayer.playAudio({
     name: titlePlayer,
     description: contentPlayer,
     url: radioUrl,
     image: {
             large: {
                     alt: radioName,
                     height: 0,
                     url: radioImageUrl,
                     width: 0,
                    },
             },
       },
      0,                 
      [
        'STOPPED',
        'PAUSED',
      ],);
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately this is not possible for a live stream, as you will only be able to generate a single media response to represent the stream. As such you'll only have one opportunity to set the description field and the other metadata.

Comment: Hi @Nick, thanks for the reply. So this is generally valid for alla streams? If I used another non-icecast stream with metadata, would I still be able to make it visible?
Thank you so much!

Comment: This is going to be the case for any stream.

Comment: Nick is not correct. Icecast is capable of injecting in stream metadata at set intervals for exactly this purpose. The challenge you will face is extracting it...

Comment: I'm referring to the context of Actions on Google, as once a stream begins your webhook is not going to be called again so there's no other opportunity to resend the metadata.